# AssertionError: negative sum of square deviations

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, statistics, standard-deviation

As part of a larger project, I am writing a function that takes in a dict of dicts of ints and returns a dict with each "outer" key linked to a tuple of the mean and standard deviation of that sub dictionary (i.e.  `(mean(dict[key1]), stdev(dict[key1]))` ). I am operating on a large dataset (the source file is a 2.8 GB csv file) and am getting an Assertion Error while calculating the standard deviation of one of the sub dicts.

While I will (and currently am) tracking down the sub dict that caused the error below, I'm curious about what general situation could cause it so I can try to avoid it if it happens further into my dataset.

The error message I receive is:

`AssertionError: negative sum of square deviations: -3734262324235.697754`

from the code:

```
import statistics as stat

try: #Check for single value error
    std = stat.stdev(val)
except stat.StatisticsError:
    std = 0
```

Comment: I've assumed you are using Python ś 3 statistics module (and edited your question) - please correct it back if it is not the case.

Comment: That's correct, my bad for forgetting to specify

Comment: The function def is on line 608 here: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/statistics.py - and the error is from the ```_ss``` function at line 493.  I'd say that looks like a check for erroneous data or an incorrect mean.

Comment: From the size of that value, maybe you are running into precision or *overflow(?)* issues (that is an uneducated guess).  If you track down the offending dataset maybe convert the data to [```decimal```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) objects and see if it behaves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in `statiscs.py` is pure Python - you seem to be a victim of a weird overflow error in the Fraction class, when processing the internal "sum of quares) `statistics._ss`  function.

I think the best thing you can do now is to isntrument the`_ss` function in the `statistics.py` file itself with an "if" and a call to `pdb.set_trace` to find interactively which data is causing the errors (there is a comment in the code that this part is subject to rounding errors). It calculates a fraction that shuld be zero - but for rounding errors, and squares that fraction. But upon squaring, the already large denominator is squared itself - which is probably triggering a bug inside Python's Fraction, and returning an extremely large value when it should be just close to zero.

Such an "if" clause can allow you to (1) bypass the error condition and run your code to the end, forcing the value to zero when the error is found; (2) note down the values that cause the error, and report that as  a bug to the Python language itself.

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem with `statistics.py` file as mentioned by @jsbueno. I also had the same error and resolved it by replacing `statistics.stdev` with `numpy.std` rather than making changes to the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with very small numbers. The accurate computation of sum(x²) gave a result of zero (Fraction(0,1)) but the accurate computation of sum(x) gave a very small, positive fraction representing the rounding errors and losses of accuracy in the substractions of the mean from the data.

The code in statistics.py indicates that total2 should be zero, but it can actually be any small number, positive or negative. The square of total2 is always a small positive fraction.

```
def _ss(data, c=None):
    """Return sum of square deviations of sequence data.

    If ``c`` is None, the mean is calculated in one pass, and the deviations
    from the mean are calculated in a second pass. Otherwise, deviations are
    calculated from ``c`` as given. Use the second case with care, as it can
    lead to garbage results.
    """
    if c is None:
        c = mean(data)
    T, total, count = _sum((x-c)**2 for x in data)
    # The following sum should mathematically equal zero, but due to rounding
    # error may not.
    U, total2, count2 = _sum((x-c) for x in data)
    assert T == U and count == count2
    total -=  total2**2/len(data)
    assert not total < 0, 'negative sum of square deviations: %f' % total
    return (T, total)
```

Therefore total, the variance, can become a negative value just before the failing assert.

The root cause is the loss of accuracy which takes place when each value is squared  in the first _sum function call. The float or np.float64 values are squared in the list comprehension by a floating point operation.

One possible way to correct, would be to cast total2 to type T before squaring it. It changes the semantics because _ss returns a value of type T instead of an exact fraction. Another, more accurate way, would be to convert x-c to Fractions once and for all before calling _sum for the first time. In both cases, the calculation would also run faster.

The most appropriate correction is not trivial because _sum also aggregates the type from successive calls to _coerce. Converting data to fractions earlier also changes the type of the result to Fraction.